# Apache2 RewriteCon

Tags: apache-http-server

We are using Apache2 and I am forcing all http connections to go to https. I have updated the conf file as follows:

```
# Call coming in has been redirected by AWS and is not secure, to fix, open the login.jsp file:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However this is causing issues and now the request is just to direct login.jsp but not all http to https.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should create a VirtualHosts for your website like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  yourwebsite.com
  ServerAlias www.yourwebsite.com
  Redirect permanent / https://yourwebsite.com/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

Place above code in conf file then restart apache2

Hop this help!